Getting ORA-01422 error when only one record exists with condition
I am attempting to select data in an Oracle PL/SQL procedure. When I select the data from the table directly like this
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_USERS
 WHERE customer_id = 'cust1234'
   AND user_id = 'cust1234user'

I get one row of data.



USERID
CUSTOMER_ID
DESCRIPTION
READ_ONLY
UPDATED_BY
CUST_API_KEY
LAST_ACCESS_DATE




cust1234user
cust1234
1234 Corporation
N
jdoe
[api_key]
3/19/2024 2:31:37 AM



However, when I put the same exact conditions in a select into query with variables, it causes an error with the description "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of row."
 customerID := 'cust1234';
 userID := 'cust1234user';
 SELECT CUST_API_KEY INTO v_encValue
   FROM CUSTOMER_USERS
  WHERE customer_id = customerID
    AND userid = userID;

How could this be happening? These two columns make up the PK, so there can't even be duplicates in this table based on that criteria. I can't tell what it thinks the additional rows are.

userid  and userID are identical, and most probably this multiplies the returning rows

This is explained in the documentation:

If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.

So when you do:
AND userid = userID

both of those userid references are for the table column; neither is for the PL/SQL variable. So that condition evaluates to true, at least for every row where userid is not null. Note that by default the slightly different case makes no difference; you just avoided the same problem with customer_id and customerID by adding the underscore to that one.
Make the PL/SQL variable names distinct from the column names. It's common to prefix variables with something (like l_userid), and if you do that then establish a naming convention for your code. In a stored PL/SQL block you can also qualify the variables with the block name (e.g. the procedure name) and table name/alias - some people prefer that.

Wow, absolutely boneheaded mistake. This is what trying to do something at the end of a 12-hour day results in. Thank you and MT0 for your answers.

When you use an identifier then Oracle will try to find the value of that identifier from the local scope - in this case the SQL query. If it does not find it then it will look at the value of identifiers in outer scopes (such as the PL/SQL variables). So your query:
SELECT CUST_API_KEY INTO v_encValue
FROM   CUSTOMER_USERS
WHERE  customer_id = customerID
AND    userid = userID;

is effectively the same as:
SELECT CUST_API_KEY INTO v_encValue
FROM   CUSTOMER_USERS u
WHERE  u.customer_id = customerID
AND    u.userid = u.userID;

Where userID is the column value and NOT the PL/SQL variable.
Always name your variables differently to the column identifiers.
DECLARE
  v_customerID CUSTOMER_USERS.CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE  := 'cust1234';
  v_userID     CUSTOMER_USERS.USERID%TYPE       := 'cust1234user';
  v_encValue   CUSTOMER_USERS.CUST_API_KEY%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT CUST_API_KEY
  INTO   v_encValue
  FROM   CUSTOMER_USERS
  WHERE  customer_id = v_customerID
  AND    userid      = v_userID;
END;
/

